# Parse simple JSON with Jackson

Tags: android, jackson

Here is my JSON:

```
{
  "i": 53691,
  "s": "Something" }
```

Here is my model:

```
    public class Test() { 
private int i;
private String s;

    public setInt(int i){ this.i = i; }

    public setString(String s){ this.s = s; }

    // getters here

    }
```

Here is my class for server's response:

```
  public class ServerResponse(){
  private Test;
 public void setTest(Test test){ this.test = test;}
 public Test getTest(){ return Test; } }
```

When I do:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(json, serverResponse);
```

I'm getting an exception like:

> JsonProcessingException: Unrecognized field "i" (Class MyClass), not
>   marked as ignorable

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make your class members public, or provide getters/setters for them.

in your case it should be:

```
public void setI() { ... }
public void setS() { ... }
```

not `setInt()` and `setString()`

personally i prefer to make them public -- shorter to write and easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is malformed.

It should be:

```
{
  "i": 53691,
  "s": "Something" 
}
```

You are missing the `,` between fields.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ for the win

Comment: I'm sorry, it was just my mistype